# GNU GRUB version 2.02 not letting me install

Tags: boot, grub2, usb

First of all, I understand that there are other questions which may have the answer. I have read and followed practically every one and I am still confused. Now that that is out of the way, my old Inspiron 3542 is not downloading Ubuntu. I am sending my laptop to family in a different country and I decided to install Ubuntu.

The bootable USB and recognization of my boot USB was easy. The place where I keep getting stopped is the installation itself. I am stuck on this screen that says **GNU GRUB version 2.02** and then asks me for an input in what looks like a grub terminal. Please respond ASAP as I need to send the laptop in a couple of days.

Comment: BTW I forgot to mention, most of my issues is the linux /vmlinuz root=/dev/sda2 command returning unknown filesystem

Comment: You can [update](https://askubuntu.com/posts/1046010/edit) your question with more details rather than adding them in the comments.